# Unexplained space in Chrome?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've got extra whitespace chrome, but no other browser on my client's website healthimpactnews.com. There is excess white space in two spots (the promo at the top, and the bottom portion of the slider below).

I've looked through the css... and I can't figure out what's causing this. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Did you do a CSS reset? You should also install firebug for chrome. It can be a very useful tool for these kind of things.

Comment: Do you mean Firebug for Firefox? Chrome has it's own built in tool which is getting better all the time.

Comment: I'm sorry guys... it was a stupid mistake. I aligned content to the bottom of the div instead of the top, so it varied with every post...

Comment: I can't help without running Firebug myself on the original page, and I can't see that problem on the site at the moment, though there is a problem with the title in Firefox overlapping the text in the paragraph at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the div is aligned to bottom and, therefore, lines up inaccurately with the top. I changed the alignment to top. No problems now.